# HTML Grid Layout with Differing Columns Per Row

Tags: html, css, layout

I was wondering if someone can give me tips on the best way of achieving the following layout using HTML:

[image: Web Grid]

I have tried using regular HTML tables but am having trouble getting the different rows with different columns.

Are there any other grid tools that you all can recommend?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use div s instead or row.. div s are faster than tablr

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using divs (hit "Run code snippet"):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  clear: both;
}

.row > div {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
}

.row-2 > div {
  width: 50%;
}

.row-3 > div {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row-2">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row row-3">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row row-2">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to mark the answer as solved (checkmark icon) to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest using a grid based system.

Bootstrap is a great example of this, find more info here: [Bootstrap grid system](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)

Other options to research would be flex-box and floats.

Thirdly, if you must use tables, you should look into the colspan attribute on td elements or just use multiple tables.

Comment: I agree, bootstrap is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't fear using a framework for achieving this, you may consider having a look at 
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/grid.html 
or 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
Both Frameworks provide the capability to achieve what you want to do (using html, css and js internally)

Answer (score 0):

Do they have to be one table?

Can you not have one table 50/50 wide, one 33/33/33 wide and another 50/50 wide?

Then again do they have to be tables at all? Aren't you more looking at grid columns rather than a table row/column paradigm?